# How do I find one tag with multiple text Content with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** a website with multiple 'p' tags with beautifulsoup and I find it very difficult.

I want to get all posts associated with p tags.
The `find_all` on beautifulsoup will not get this done and the image is not saving I get an error that the file cannot be saved and tell me how to retrieve, add or **scrape** all the text in p tags and the image on the HTML code below.

my code

```
kompas = requests.get('https://url_on_html.com/')
beautify = BeautifulSoup(kompas.content,'html5lib')

news = beautify.find_all('div', {'class','jeg_block_container'})
arti = []

for each in news:
    title = each.find('h3', {'class','jeg_post_title'}).text
    lnk = each.a.get('href')
    r = requests.get(lnk)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')
    content = soup.find('p').text.strip()
    images = soup.find_all('img')

    arti.append({
        'Headline': title,
        'Link': lnk,
        'image': 'images'
        })
```

let's take this HTML code as a **scraping** sample

```
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p>Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
<script></script>
<p>the emergency of our matter is Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
<p> we will not once in Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well. 
</p>
<script></script>
<br></br>
<script></script>
<p>king of our Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
<script></script>
<img src="image.png">
<p>he is our Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
<p>some weas Once upon a time there were three little sisters, and their names were and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>
```

I want to filter and **scrape** all the 'p' tags and add them to my content.

The issue is find_all attribute on beautifulsoup can not retrieve this.
The find all attributes will just **scrape** the first line of the p element or elements.

Comment: FYI ‘to scrap’ and ‘scrapping’ mean to throw away like rubbish. You should use __scrape__ and __scraping__ for what you’re doing

Answer (score 0):

You are running `soup.find`, not `soup.find_all`. `find_all` will return a list of all `p`'s. You cannot run `text.strip()` on a list, so let's wrap it in a list comprehension that does it for all independent items:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')
content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
```

now `content` is a list of strings. If you want to turn this list into a single string you can run:

```
content = ' '.join(content)
```

About the image, `soup.find_all('img')` will also return a list of images. To extract the link you will also need to do this for all images in the list independently: `images = [i['src'] for i in soup.find_all('img')]`.

This makes:

```
kompas = requests.get('https://url_on_html.com/')
beautify = BeautifulSoup(kompas.content,'html5lib')

news = beautify.find_all('div', {'class','jeg_block_container'})
arti = []

for each in news:
    title = each.find('h3', {'class','jeg_post_title'}).text
    lnk = each.a.get('href')
    r = requests.get(lnk)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')
    content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
    content = ' '.join(content)
    images = [i['src'] for i in soup.find_all('img')]

    arti.append({
        'Headline': title,
        'Link': lnk,
        'image': images,
        'content': content
        })
```

Comment: there are multiple images sir

Comment: thanks for your reply i will really test it now and get back to you immediately

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer for multiple images.

Comment: sir.  RJ Adriaansen is there any possibiliy of me excluding the last p tags list limit the numbers of p tags

Comment: You can slice the list of `p`'s. Say you want to remove the last 5 items from the list: `content = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')][:-5]`. You can change the 5 with any other number.